# react-native: can't focus in TextInput by Pressing a button

Tags: react-native

I want to focus in TextInput and make the keyboard pop up by pressing a button.But it didn't work. So how to solve it?
Here is my code.

```
<TextInput ref="myInput"  />
<Text onPress={()=> this.refs["myInput"].focus()>custom</Text>
```

Answer (score 3):

replace this line:

```
<Text onPress={()=> { this.refs.myInput.focus();} }>custom</Text>
```

You have not closed `}` brace and syntax issue